# How to put rounded corners to canvas image?

Tags: image, flutter, canvas, rounded-corners, custompaging

I am drawing an image on Canvas in following manner.

```
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.white;

    canvas.drawImageRect(
        img,
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, img.width.toDouble(), img.height.toDouble()),
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, newImgWidth, newImgHeight),
        paint);
}
```

I want to give rounded corners to this image.

Can anyone provide some help on how to do something like that?

Comment: there is a clipRRect method in canvas, which will clip (with rounded rect) whatever is painted

Comment: can you please provide some code?

Answer (score 1):

Lets make a try to use `clipRRect()` method of `Canvas` class

Add following code snippet inside your `paint()` method and
change the value `20` with your required radius value

```
canvas.clipRRect(
  RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(20, 20, 20, 20); // left, top, right, bottom
);
```

Full version

```
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.white;

    canvas.clipRRect(
      RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(20, 20, 20, 20); // left, top, right, bottom
    );

    canvas.drawImageRect(
        img,
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, img.width.toDouble(), img.height.toDouble()),
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, newImgWidth, newImgHeight),
        paint);
}
```

Comment: I tried it. Does not seems to have any effect on the image

Comment: @janaka if it not showing any effect because you are missing the named parameters of RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners

Comment: @Yadu not clear what you mean. Can you explain little more?

Comment: See my answer @janaka

Answer (score 0):

let me give you code sample

```
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.white;

    canvas.clipRRect(
      RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(0, 0, img.width.toDouble(), img.height.toDouble(),topLeft:20,topRight:20,bottomLeft:20,bottomRight:20); // left, top, right, bottom
    );

    canvas.drawImageRect(
        img,
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, img.width.toDouble(), img.height.toDouble()),
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, newImgWidth, newImgHeight),
        paint);
}
```

you have to match the coordinates of RRect and the ImageRect that you want to clip